# Add filtering capability to module view - Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla-3.x

I need ability to filter records in my **module**, but I don't know how to add filter form to module (in component everything works perfectly).

Similar question have been asked a while ago ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893091/joomla-filter-form-in-module-for-component-auto-fill-fields)), but the answer is a bit unclear (where does the array of `$filters` come from?).

The main question is **is it even possible to add fully functional filtering box using Joomla CMS API?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you have stored value to session from request need to get value from there and assign to variable again:

So to fetch value from session :

```
$com_man_filtervalues = $app->getUserStateFromRequest('com_man.oferty.filter', 'filter', array(), 'array');
//print_r($com_man_filtervalues);//you need to check for values
```

If you have got values properly there then you can directly set them to variable when you have display them:

[Joomla method_getInput](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JForm.html#method_getInput)

```
getInput(string $name, string $group = null, mixed $value = null);
```